# Make blender particles a specific shape?

Tags: particles

I have just followed and completed a tutorial that made a woodchipping effect on the text. this is a link to it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YFmN7eTNfNw

I would like a specific shape for the particles that come off, though. Is this possible? I am new to blender and stack exchange so please so your help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the render panel in the particle system options check **"object"** and select your object.[image: render]

Comment: This was very helpful. I just need to convert my image now :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

- Checkerboard with a particle system
- Group specified under the Render Panel as shown in render panel.
- Group contains two different shapes shown in outliner window.
- Your group can contain more shapes for many wood chips
- Groups are created by selecting multiple objects and pressing Control-G

Answer (score 0):

You can use any mesh object or groups of meshes as shape for your particle systems.

Under the Properties Window > Particles > Render panel you can choose the type of particle to use, in your case either *Object* or *Group*.
Use object if you wish to use a single object as particle, or group to use all objects in a group as particles assigned randomly or by order.

You can then model your mesh(es) separately as desired, make sure you keep polygon counts in check so your render times don't explode to very high values.